# Simplifying Weistrass equation with characteristic $3$

Tags: number-theory

I want to simplify the Weierstrass equation $$y^2 = x^3 + Cx^2 + Ax + B$$ in a field with characteristic $3$ in such a way that the new equation is of the form $$(y')^2 = (x')^3 + A'x + B\,'.$$ Is there such a way?

Comment: Unless $C=0$, you just can't get rid of it, can you?

Answer (score 0):

To go into things a bit more deeply than Lord Shark has in his/her/its comment, a curve of genus $g$ in characteristic $p>0$ has an important invariant, the “Hasse matrix” a $g$-by-$g$ matrix with coefficients in the base. Even for elliptic curves, it’s a bit tricky to describe it, but for a given curve its zeroness or nonzeroness is intrinsic. In characteristic three, though, the Hasse invariant of a curve in form $y^2=x^3+Cx^2+Ax+B$ is simply $C$. Thus you can’t get rid of $C$ if it started out nonzero.

What’s Hasse good for? If it’s zero, the elliptic curve has only the identity as its $p$-torsion subgroup. If it’s nonzero, this group will have order $p$ (never $p^2$ ! ) but of course you may need to go to a finite extension of the base to catch the full $p$ of them.